# What is a <class 'range'>

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, range

Python3:

```
string = range(10)
print("{}".format(type(string)))
```

The output:

```
class 'range'
```

I am just curious about this class 'range'.
Could anyone explain?

But in Python2:

The output:

```
class 'list'
```

Well, it is self explanatory

Answer (score 5):

In Python 2 `range(val)` produces an instance of a list, it [simply a function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range). Thereby `type(range(10))` will return `class 'list'`.

In Python `3`, [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) is equivalent to [`xrange`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-xrange) in Python 2 and it returns an instance of a new class named `range`. For more changes/differences between Python 2/3 see [`PEP 3100`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3100/#built-in-namespace).

Answer (score 5):

Python 3 added a new [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) class to efficiently handle "an immutable sequence of numbers" (similar to Python 2's [`xrange`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-xrange)). Python 2 does not have such a range class, so the `range` function just returns a list.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference for python3 (taken from https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range)

> The advantage of the range type over a regular list or tuple is that a
> range object will always take the same (small) amount of memory, no
> matter the size of the range it represents (as it only stores the
> start, stop and step values, calculating individual items and
> subranges as needed).

Comment: Is this really worth posting a new answer, though? If you think it's important, it could easily be added to Mureinik's answer from 2016 via a simple edit.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35478369)